# Reorder TreeView with Drag & Drop

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

The end goal I'm trying to reach is to be able to reorder `TreeView` items by dragging and dropping them into their new order. I'm getting a casting error when I try to get the original object, "ModeObject", from the `TreeViewItem`... I'm doing the exact same operation on a `ListView` so I'm not sure why this is giving me an error.

```
ModeObject mo = (ModeObject)tv.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(tvitem);
```

> Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type
>   'ModeObject'.

---

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="1" Name="tvModes" ItemsSource="{Binding Modes}" AllowDrop="True">
  <TreeView.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
     </Style>
  </TreeView.Resources>

  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type fixtures:ModeObject}" ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}">
        <Grid>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" MouseDown="ModeNameTextBlock_MouseDown" Width="Auto"/>
           <TextBox LostFocus="ModeNameTextBox_LostFocus" KeyDown="ModeNameTextBox_KeyDown" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

---

```
public ObservableCollection<Mode> Modes { get; set; }

...

private void TvModes_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e) {
   Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
   Vector diff = modeReorderStartPoint - mousePos;
   if (e.LeftButton == System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
      (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
      Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)) {

      TreeView tv = sender as TreeView;
      TreeViewItem tvitem = FindAncestor<TreeViewItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
      ModeObject mo = (ModeObject)tv.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(tvitem);

      DataObject dragData = new DataObject("reorderMode", mo);
      DragDrop.DoDragDrop((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);

   }
}
```

---

```
public class Mode {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ModeObject> Channels { get; set; }

        public Mode() {
            Channels = new ObservableCollection<ModeObject>();
        }

    }

    public class ModeObject {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ChannelIndex { get; set; }
    }
```

What exactly is `MS.Internal.NamedObject` and how do I go about resolving this error?

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but maybe useful for someone with the same problem.
As this tree is data bound, you can access the data object for each tree item from its data context rather than the ItemContainerGenerator.
In the case of the example provided, the old line:

```
ModeObject mo = (ModeObject)tv.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(tvitem);
```

is replaced with:

```
ModeObject mo = (ModeObject)tvitem.DataContext;
```